# How to open AVD manager in Android Studio 3.0 version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

after I update Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0 version. I can not find AVD Manager in Tools/Android/AVD Manager.

[image: Option under tools]

Comment: I can run the AVD Manager without installing Android Studio by running this command: `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android.bat`

Answer (score 56):

I just did a fresh install and had the same issue. Solved by:

- Click "Install missing platforms(s)..." in the highlighted error:

[image: Messages panel]

- Then after the download/install, click "Intall Build Tools...":

[image: Messages panel]

- Then after the download/install, you will see Android under Tools menu

Comment: Thanks! I had to click it multiple times, but eventually it worked

Comment: Would be nice if you could say what/where the "Install missing platforms" button is..

Answer (score 41):

**If you have never used Android Studio Before, and do not have a Project**
..Opening the AVD Manager is even trickier!!

For example, if you are installing it to use an emulator for a **`create-react-native-app`** project., but aren't otherwise using Android Studio to write or manage your app.
Here is how you can gain access to the AVD Manager.
AVD Manager is required to set-up your emulators.
Android Studio Documentation does *NOT* tell you *how to gain access* to AVD Manager.  It *starts* at `Open the AVD Manager`!

**I Just Need the emulator (and manager)**.
But I did not even have the window the OP refers to.
Nothing in the `Configure` menu, not `Preferences` (even `Preferences -> Tools`) gave me access to AVD Manager.

So in my case it was even more confusing to have *No Direct Access AVD Manager* !

Nor did I have an `android` folder in my create-react-native-app app, so [hamdi's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846636/5411817) did not work for me.

All I had was a new folder/git repo from:
`create-react-native-app`

**My Solution**
On the Android Studio Startup Screen, I choose:
`Import Android Code Sample`
Then choose any sample. (I choose the first example listed).

Then (after a bunch of downloading/building..), then brought up the window the OP refers to.
I then had to update gradle, as mentioned by [user1449542's post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358410/5411817).
At that point, [Muhammad Hannan's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948654/5411817) was helpful !!!
I clicked the icon from the bottom image in his post -- vioa!
( Alternatively from the menu bar choose: `Tools -> AVD Manager` )

---

#### **Better Solution:**

I have since realized that the Startup Screen Option:
**`Start a new Android Studio Project`**
also works and is even quicker (less to download/build), and might not even need `gradle` file updates (mentioned by another post) that I had to do when I downloaded a sample project.

Just use the default settings to create a dummy project in the default location, and choose
**`Add No Activity`**.

Android Studio will "build" this dummy project, and set it up, then open the Window you need to access said icon, and/or menu bar.
In the future, this dummy project will appear on the left of Android Studio's Startup Screen.
Just click on that dummy project to re-open the window you need to access AVD Manager.
Then, as before, click that icon (or from the menu bar choose: **`Tools -> AVD Manager`**) to create/edit AVD emulators.

---

If you're using React Native (create react native app), you can [start an emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#starting), once you have created an AVD emulator, and probably won't need to open Android Studio itself. (see notes below).

**Be sure to start the emulator *before* choosing `a`** (from the terminal window that's running your app via `yarn start`).

---

**Additional Notes for reference:**

To start the emulator from the command line:
`emulator -avd <avd_emulator_name>`

To list what emulators have been configured:
`emulator -list-avds`

> AVD_Nexus_6P_API_23
>   AVD_Pixel_2_XL_API_27
>   AVD_Pixel_XL_API_25

So, for example, I can do this:
`emulator -avd AVD_Pixel_2_XL_API_27`

---

Additional Information

I also had to add the following lines to my `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 10`
```

Note: the value between the back-ticks is what the JAVA install from my terminal replied.  If you type that part into terminal by itself, it spits out the location Java was installed. If you have an different version of Java installed, just replace `10` with your version.

I then got the following path from:
 - Android Studio Startup Screen -> Configure -> SDK ManagerPreferences
 - Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK
 - Android SDK Location: `/Users/sherylhohman/Library/Android/sdk`

and used it as the value for adding the following line

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/sherylhohman/Library/Android/sdk
```

Though I chose to write it as the following instead:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Finally I added:

```
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb

export PATH
```

*I may not have needed the `...adb` or 1 or more of the last PATH entries.

This was a cumulation of many internet searches, many conflicting solutions.  The major missing key was accessing AVD Manager (OP's question), which finally solved the problem.  This just happens to be the items I had already added to my .batch_profile along the way trying to get the android emulator working inside my create-react-native-app App!.*

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so helpful! Exactly, nowhere in the google docs it goes through adding an emulator if you've never used the Android Studio before... ‍♀️

Answer (score 34):

I found this just under the toolbar in Android Studio (v3.2):

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is so help, it is happening a lot build fails, then I found it has to wipe data from Android stuidio

Answer (score 21):

Go to the "Event Log" tab in the bottom right corner.[image]

There will probably be some error messages. It will provide information and links to resolve the problem. Then the buttons will not be greyed out anymore.

[image]

Comment: Worked, but in the first run, doesnt open existing project. Create a new blank project!

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 on Ubuntu I have AVD under Tools > Android > AVD [image: AVD]. And also on the right upper corner of the screen.  [image: AVD]

**EDIT :**
Go to Settings and search for AVD.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I try to search AVD Manager, it appears but show disabled gray status.

Comment: verify your Android studio SDK installation. Try to run Android studio in administrator mode.

Answer (score 9):

If you encountered the problem when using **React Native**, you are probably trying to include the whole project in **Android Studio**. You only have to include the ***android*** folder from the **React Native** project. After this process, **Gradle** will be synchronized and ***AVD Manager*** will come back.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
If you get this message: "Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project" then click on it and add Android.
After that, the icons should be enabled now.

Comment: How silly to make this a requirement for new users...

Answer (score 2):

you can  find SDK manager,AVD manager TOP right side on android studio version more than 3.2.0.

and if you want to run via commmand promat you can go to 
cd Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
./avdmanager list

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Windows 10 and saw this solution in another post ... It worked for me.

Set-up the System Environmental Variables ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

- To do this ...

  - Click the windows key and start typing System.
  - Select it when it pops up in the menu.
  - Click advanced system settings
  - Select the advanced tab
  - Click Environmental Variables at the bottom
  - Under system variables, click new
  - Enter the variable name
  - For value, enter the the path to the Android SDK, which will most likely be:
        C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
  - Use the same path for both variables

Answer (score 1):

In Andriod Studio 3.5 its here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Press shift twice times while being on Android Studio

   - This will open the search window.
2. Search - Virtual Device Manager".
3. Click on it it will open Device add window.
4. Click Add device to add new device.

Answer (score 0):

Following the event log to install resolves the issue [image: install plugins]

Answer (score 0):

Hit ctrl+shift+a and search avd and click on it

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to find AVD manager in android studio easily for Android studio version 3.1.2.In order to launch AVD manager, i had to create a sample project and then launch it from there.

I have documented all my steps here, in case any one wants to get benifitted.

[How to launch AVD manager on Android Studio 3.1.2](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/11/14/avd-manager/)