# NO Android option in "tool" menu, and no avd manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Problem : No AVD manager in Android Studio, and no "Android" option in the "tool" menu.

Tried solutions :

- re-install (twice)
- changed installation partition to the one containing the Android SDK directory
- went to "configure" - "project default" - "project structure", and checked my Adroid SDK directory (it's there)
- open a new project - there is still no android menu, and no avd manager.
- instead of "Android" in the "tool" menu, i have "Kotlin"
- i tried to use terminal, and console, to launch android avd : not opening
- i tried to search for Android, or AVD, in the search option. they show, but when i click, nothing happens
- i saw people saying i needed 5gig storage to install Android Studio. but when i install mine, it only offers one option, and total is 2gig. but i have way more than enough storage space on both my partition for 5gig or 50gig
- i tried to customize toolbar, but Android options are just not there to be made visible
- i have read all the posts here regarding this issue, and have not found a solution that works.

It must be a simple step that i am missing, but which one ???
 -

Comment: I've seen that before and it was basically a matter of waiting, it didn't get that menu until it had run through some post boot initialization steps.

Comment: I also had the same problem, reinstalled the Android Studio and it didn't work. However, I noticed that when I create a new android project there is a gradle error message that says some sdk versions are missing. After I installed those missing sdk versions, I was finally able to see the Tools > Android menu. Try installing some sdk packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open AVD manager in Android Studio 3.0 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948322/how-to-open-avd-manager-in-android-studio-3-0-version)

Answer (score 0):

Which Android Studio are you trying to use?
I am using 3.0 and I see both "Android" and "Kotlin" submenus under "Tools".
I am using macOS 10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but it's resolved now.

Follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Run the unistaller from Control Panel if you are using windows.
2. After you have uninstalled Android Studio, it is recommended that you restart the machine before proceeding with the steps below.
3. To remove and delete the remains of Android studio setting files;

   - Go to C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]
   - Delete .android, .AndroidStudio and any versions of this directory with versions on the end, .gradle and .m2.
   - Then, go to C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\Roaming and delete the JetBrains directory. (If any, else ignore).
   - Finally, go to C:\Program Files and delete the Android directory.
   - Delete any remains of the SDK, in Windows Explorer, C:\Users[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\AppData\Local and delete the Android directory.
   - (Optional) Delete all previous projects AndroidStudioProjects directory.
4. Instal Android Studio
5. Wait till after sometime a prompt will appear to  standard or custom installation

   - Select Custom Installation and make sure Android virtual device is selected there and continue install.
6. Once everything is done.. Create a project with basic actvity and then wait.. It atleast take 5- 10 minutes to load... At the end you will see Gradle build finished in the console.
7. You may get errors in console. There will be link to fix all these errors at the console only if there are any errors.. click on those links and those will get automatically fixed. Do this till the console errors goes away.
8. Then view Tools menu hopefully you should find ANDROID menu option there :)