# Where is AVD Manager?

Tags: android-studio, nativescript

I am trying to get started with NativeScript. The installation steps outlines to install Android Studio. Which I did.

Then I have to mock around something with AVD Manager. According to the docs the AVD Manager is under Tools > Android > AVD Manager. Well, it is not.

NativeScript docs: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/android-virtual-devices

Android docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

I have googled, looked up in both docs and they all say that AVD Manager is under the tools menu. I have enclosed the screenshot I see in Android Studio. It is not there. I went through Preferences, Settings, Menus, god knows what else.

What could be so "obvious" that I am missing!?

Android Studio v3.0.1

OS X 10.11.6

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do any of the [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948322/how-to-open-avd-manager-in-android-studio-3-0-version) help?

Comment: Have you installed any of the Android SDK? The error at the bottom is more important than the AVD

Comment: @NikosC. Yes, thank you! That even log thing solved the missing Tools menu.