# Avd Manager not visible in Android Studio

Tags: react-native

I have installed Android Studio but could not access the AVD Manager. It is disabled and not found in the toolbar. I want it to work with react native.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open AVD manager in Android Studio 3.0 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948322/how-to-open-avd-manager-in-android-studio-3-0-version)

Answer (score 0):

AVD Manager isn't available immediately. You should wait until Android Studio load all dependencies. [The best solution is to run it from the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line).
For mac:

```
${ANDROID_SDK}/emulator -avd DEVICE_NAME
```