# How to open emulator from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently installed android studio. I need to open/create android emulators how can i do that, I am not able to find AVD Manager option. Below option is not available 
 Open the AVD Manager by clicking **Tools > Android > AVD Manager**.

[image: Android Studio]

Here Emulator option is disabled

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open AVD manager in Android Studio 3.0 version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948322/how-to-open-avd-manager-in-android-studio-3-0-version)

Comment: @Nilesh I am not able to find _install missing component option_ as described in above question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed Android Emulator option in SDK tool,

Go to File --> Settings, Now follow the image and install Android Emulator.

> [image]

After installing, restart the Studio and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Yeah exactly haven't installed these components. Now it is working.

Answer (score 8):

Open `Emulator` Android Studio.

Check the picture. Android Studio 3.0.1

[image: Picture]

Comment: That icon is dissable for me.See my updated pictures in attachment

Answer (score 5):

Check Image

[image]

Click on AVD Manager, new Screen Will appear. So choose emulator if you already have any emulator or Create Virtual device and clone it.

Comment: See me question I am not able to find AVD manager. This option is disable for me.

Comment: If you running android studio in non administrator mode, then close android studio and run it in administrator mode. You will see screen saying "android framework is identified" Click on the configure link on that notification. The AndroidStudio will start configuring the android sdk. After some time the buttons would be visible and enabled. I hope this might help you :)

Comment: i'm surprising, just a little mistake